# DNS Management for Tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, a-records

I have a tomcat server running perfectly at `http://68.169.56.63:8080` I have a subdomain http://solar.wbe.in. Now I want my website http://solar.wbe.in to point to that tomcat server so that if I open http://solar.wbe.in site my browser it should show `http://68.169.56.63:8080` I was looking at A records in DNS management. It has option to map IP but not port number. How do I map port 80 of http://solar.wbe.in to port 8080 of `http://68.169.56.63`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the port in the Tomcat Server.xml e.g

```
<Connector port="80" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Or you could install a webserver like apache to listen on port 80 and proxy the requests through to Tomact either use mod_jk or mod_proxy.